# On this Kmett CRC article, why does ab = a0^n + 0^m b? What does this notation mean?

Tags: haskell, math, crc

In [Edward Kmett's article on CRCs](https://www.schoolofhaskell.com/user/edwardk/parallel-crc#exploiting-weakness) it has the following derivation:

```
CRC(ab) =                               -- definition of CRC
crc(INIT,ab) + FINAL =                  -- linearity
crc(INIT,a0^n + 0^m b) + FINAL =        -- additive homomorphism
crc(INIT,a0^n) + crc(0,0^nb) + FINAL =  -- zero blindness 
crc(INIT,a0^n) + crc(0,b) + FINAL       -- definition of crc
crc(crc(INIT,a),0^n) + crc(0,b) + FINAL -- additive homomorphism
crc(crc(INIT,0^m)+crc(0,a),0^n) + crc(0,b) + FINAL
```

What in the world is `a0^n` and `0^m b`? Are these powers, like `a * pow(0, n)`? If so, wouldn't 0^n = 0? Or XOR? Something else entirely? Is the space significant? I am not understanding why, for example:

```
ab = a0^n + 0^m b
```

and why `0^m b` became `0^nb` between the third and fourth lines?

Comment: https://wiki.haskell.org/Power_function

Comment: @Mika'il As I said, wouldn't `0^n = 0` ? Makes no sense.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

He's using a notation for bit strings. Here *a* and *b* are bit strings of length *m* and *n* respectively.

```
ab    =  a concatenated with b
0^n   =  the bit string of length n consisting of all 0s
a0^n  =  a concatenated with 0^n
0^m b = 0^m concatenated with b
a0^n + 0^m b  = sum of a0^n and 0^m b (same as the bitwise OR in this case)
              = a concatenated with b
```